# Maximize, Minimize, Exit in the global menu

Tags: unity, 13.04

When I have a program like Firefox and the terminal maximized I have the minimize, maximize and exit controls in the global menu (at the top).

I really don't like it, is it possible to get it to the program like in GNOME or Windows?

Comment: change to some different [desktop environment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available?rq=1). I think you don't have any other option. :)

Comment: I guess you should install another desktop environment :/